# How can I create a list of method references?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I have a need to work through a list and for each item call a different method on a target object.  It seems elegant that I could just create a list of method references to do this, so for each index in the list, I could call the appropriate method reference that corresponds to it.

```
private final static List<Consumer<String>> METHODS = (List<Consumer<String>>) Arrays.asList(
     TargetClass::setValue1,
     TargetClass::setValue2,
     TargetClass::setValue3,
     TargetClass::setValue4,
     TargetClass::setValue5);
```

However, Eclipse is flagging these with the error *The target type of this expression must be a functional interface*.  Now, TargetClass here is a regular class, not an interface ... does that mean there is no way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Why are you casting a list into a `Consumer<String>`? And trying to store a list into a `Consumer<String>`? If we forget about method-references here, would you store the result `Arrays.asList("foo")` into a `String`?

Comment: please, provide a code of the `TargetClass` class

Comment: Sorry, my fault ... corrected, but same problem.  The error is compile time on the method references ... not on the casting.

Comment: TargetClass is Avro generated code ... it's very ugly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible your method references don't match the `Consumer<String>` functional interface.

This code, for example, passes compilation :

```
 private final static List<Consumer<String>> METHODS = Arrays.asList(
     Double::valueOf,
     Integer::valueOf,
     String::length);
```

Since your methods don't seem to be static, they don't match `Consumer<String>`, since these methods have an additional implicit parameter - the instance that the method would be applied on.

You can use a `BiConsumer<TargetClass,String>` :

```
private final static List<BiConsumer<TargetClass,String>> METHODS = Arrays.asList(
     TargetClass::setValue1,
     TargetClass::setValue2,
     TargetClass::setValue3,
     TargetClass::setValue4,
     TargetClass::setValue5);
```

Comment: I'm sorry - you are correct ... copied the code incorrectly when trying to make it "generic" for posting here.  yes, List<Consumer<String>> ... but the same error results.

Comment: @Steve Perhaps the method references you are passing do not match the `Consumer<String>` functional interface.

Comment: The generated code by Avro looks like this:  
    `public Builder setValue1(CharSequence value) {
        validate(fields()[50], value);
        this.value1 = value;
        fieldSetFlags()[50] = 1;
        return this;
    }`

I tried changing to Consumer<CharSequence> but it didn't help.

Comment: @Steve It `setValue1` is not static, it doesn't match `Consumer<String>`. It would match `BiConsumer<TheClassThatContainsThatMethod,CharSequence>`.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you!  I'm still trying to get method references under my feet.  That did work!