# Pass a class method to another class method

Tags: java

Say I have the following class

```
class Application {
    public Application() {...}

    public void doSomething(final String logs) {
        final String[] lines = logs.split("\\n");
        for (final String line: lines) {
           // Pass the line to every single checkForProp# item and do something with the response
        }
    } 

    private Optional<Action> checkForProp1(final String line) {
       // Check if line has certain thing
       // If so return an Action
    }

    // More of these "checks" here
}
```

Let's say every single response, would be added to a queue, and then returned something is done on that queue.

So instead of I calling each method manually, I want to have maybe an array of checker methods, and automatically loop through them, pass in the line, and add the response to a queue.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: you can use `interface` for this

Comment: You could probably create an interfacr and create a class, you'd be stuck having to create instances for every single one, it's probably easier adding the checks manually

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383246/how-can-i-create-a-list-of-method-references ?

Comment: If order of checks doesn't matter, then you probably could use some annotation to "mark" checks and some reflection to call them (find methods annotated with @XXX then call them)

Comment: @RC I like the annotation method!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your Action as interface:

```
public interface Action{
   public void fireAction();
}
```

Those classes which implement Action will then override the method defined in the interface, such as checking a String.

Add the instances of Action to the list and you loop them accordingly.

Example:

```
for(Action a : actions)
    a.fireAction();
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly then following code may be help you.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
```

public class AClass {

```
private void aMethod(){
    System.out.println(" in a");
}

private void bMethod(){
    System.out.println(" in b");
}

private void cMethod(){
    System.out.println(" in c");
}

private void dMethod(){
    System.out.println(" in d");
}

//50 more methods. 

//method call the rest
public void callAll() {
     Method[] methods = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    try{
    for (Method m : methods) {

        if (m.getName().endsWith("Method")) {
            //do stuff..
            m.invoke(this,null);
        }
    }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
AClass a=new AClass();
a.callAll();
 }
    }
```

Here Java Reflection is used.